# how to use libsvm model file in opencv

Tags: opencv, svm, libsvm

I am developing an OCR using SVM in opencv C++. SVM used is (one vs one multi-class) linear SVM. Opencv svm (multi-class)doesn't give probability estimates for each class that was used in time of training. So i tried my luck with libsvm Multi-class classification (and probability output) via error-correcting codes. It gave me the probability estimates for each of the class, now I want to use the training model file in opencv C++. I get an error. Now my problem is how to use the training model in opencv, if not possible how to get probability estimates for each of the class using (one vs one multi-class) linear svm ?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with OpenCV, but doesn't it have a logistic regression class (like Liblinear)? That's much easier to get probability estimates from and its training criterion is awfully close to that of a linear SVM.

Comment: In opencv the output is the label which has the highest probability value, but I need probability value for further calculation.

Comment: I doubt that OpenCV trains SVMs for probability outputs if it doesn't actually output them. Maybe [this question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/1424/get-a-probability-out-of-svm-predict/) is helpful?